# Is there a way to listen for changes to a Web Audio AudioParam?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

Is there a way to listen for changes to a Web Audio AudioParam? For example:

```
let context = new AudioContext();
let volume = context.createGain();
volume.addEventListener("statechange", evt => {
  console.log("it would be nice if this worked:", evt);
});
volume.setValueAtTime(0.001, context.currentTime + 10 * Math.random());
```

I cannot seem to find any documentation on MDN that explains how to listen for changes like these, so that they can be hooked into by other code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like for now (Sept. 2018) this is not a thing, so I've filed https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues/1756 and https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues/1757 in the hopes that, eventually, it will be.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do that, and it's not even clear if it makes sense.  You can automate an AudioParam with, say, a linear ramp.  What is the statechange event you want to catch then? What is the actual "state"?  These would seem to be ill-defined.

Comment: Same as a scroll event in the browser: fire a million events as the value changes over time, at the shortest permissible event interval, and let the user write their own curbing. They'd be on the hook for making sure to act on, ignore, or even (temporarily or permanently) unregister the listener. With that said: this is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans the case of the scroll event is very different though. All these scroll events are fired because they were all the default behavior coming after a wheel event. When this scroll happens programatically, or by other means than such wheel events (e.g space keypress or scrollTo()) only one scroll event fires, even though this scroll behavior can be smooth.

Comment: sure, but ramps are also "manual" in the sense that I initiated the transition and there is a well-defined end to that transition. The solution for that case already exists, and is implemented by all major browsers using `transitionStart` and `transitionEnd` events. The context might be different (Namely, CSS) but the problem is the same. that's a solved problem and I will happily take a `transitionStart` and `transitionEnd` event for AudioParams if there is one! I didn't see one in the spec though =(

Comment: No there is none, I think only [AudioScheduledSourceNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioScheduledSourceNode) have time based events. You might want to use it in parallel, but a regular setTimeout might do just as well.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using setTimeout at the moment, it feels super gross to have to parallel-call each and every value change, rather than just having an event available. I guess I'll have to start posting on the webaudio list, to request a better event model.

Comment: Any node with an `AudioParam` has time-based events.  This is most nodes with attributes.